# Flutter JSON Convert from string or how to get JSON data from dialogflow

Tags: json, string, flutter, dialogflow-es

I'm using flutter_dialogflow LIBRARY to get Dialogflow data. I got this type of string so that I can't map it into a JSON formatter is there any to covert this type of JSON string to JSON in a flutter.

AIResponse aiResponse = await dialogflow.detectIntent(query);
print(aiResponse.getListMessage());

flutter: [{text: {text: []}}, {payload: {ignoreTextResponse: false, metadata: {contentType: 300, templateId: 6, payload: [{title: Symptoms of COVID-19, message: What are the symptoms of Corona virus?}, {message: What if I have symptoms?, title: What if I have symptoms?}, {title: How does it spread?, message: How does it spread?}, {message: Why only designated labs do the  test?, title: Why only designated labs do the  test?}, {title: What precautions should I take?, message: What precautions should I take?}, {message: Household cleaning tips, title: Household cleaning tips}, {title: Covid-19 FAQs, message: Covid-19 FAQs}]}, message: Hi! Please select from below, platform: kommunicate}}]

Comment: That method 'getListMessage()' is a List<dynamic> right? Or return a string

Comment: yes it's return String i need json

Comment: take a look at json.decode() https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html